# How to add a number at the end of a certain line for multiple files in Linux?

Tags: linux

I have a list of files, the file names are `file1.txt, file2.txt, ..., file100.txt`.

Within each file, the content is as follows:

```
abcd

efgh

ijkl

data

wxyz
```

How can I add a number to the end of the 4th line for multiple files in Linux, such that the new content for `file1.txt` is:

```
abcd

efgh

ijkl

data1

wxyz
```

and the content for `file2.txt` is:

```
abcd

efgh

ijkl

data2

wxyz
```

etc.

Comment: You can post your effort and observations without any hesitations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are usually many ways to accomplish any goal in Bash, depending on the exact nature of the problem.  However this line seems close to what you're asking for:

```
printf '%s\0' {1..100} | xargs -0 -I{} sed -i 4s/$/{}/ file{}.txt
```

The `printf` command is used with brace expansion to create a string consisting of the numbers `1` through `100` separated by null bytes.  (`printf` is a very useful command and sometimes follows the principle of least surprise a little bit better than the `echo` command does, IMHO.)

Then the `xargs` command is used to run a command for each of these.  The `-0` flag tells it that the input items are separated by null bytes (rather than whitespace), and the `-I{}` argument tells it to search through the command and replace the string `{}` with the item.  The command given to `xargs` is `sed -i 4s/$/{}/ file{}.txt`.  The `4` is an address that refers to the 4th line of the file.  The `s/$/{}/` matches the end-of-line marker and replaces the match with the value between the right-hand pair of slashes.  `file{}.txt` obviously refers to the `{}`'th file.

The result of this is that the following commands are run:

```
sed -i 4s/$/1/ file1.txt
sed -i 4s/$/2/ file2.txt
...
sed -i 4s/$/100/ file100.txt
```

This is very specific to the question as asked, since it is these exact commands that are executed, so buyer beware if your situation is actually more general than this.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! It works on my laptop. May I further ask how can I insert the number in the 3rd position of the 4th line, rather than the end of the 4th line?  I am new to Linux and I apologize for the silly question... Also, is there any book you would recommend me to read?